# Is there an analytic solution for the equation $\log_{2}{x}+\log_{3}{x}+\log_{4}{x}=1$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

[image]

I am looking for a close form solution for below equation.

$$\log_{2}{x}+\log_{3}{x}+\log_{4}{x}=1.$$

I solve it by graphing, but I don't know is there a way to find $x$ analytically  ?

Answer (score 16):

It's $$\ln{x}\left(\frac{1}{\ln2}+\frac{1}{\ln3}+\frac{1}{\ln4}\right)=1$$ or
$$\ln{x}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\ln2}+\frac{1}{\ln3}+\frac{1}{\ln4}}$$ or
$$x=e^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\ln2}+\frac{1}{\ln3}+\frac{1}{\ln4}}}$$

Comment: For incognito, which up-votes my answers. If you indeed so like my solutions then do it please not so often, otherwise the system removes your work. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Let $y = log_{10}x$

Then

$y(\frac{1}{log2}+\frac{1}{log3}+\frac{1}{log4}) = 1$

Find y

and then $x = 10^y$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\log[b](x) = \dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\tag1 
\log_{2}{x}+\log_{3}{x}+\log_{4}{x}=1$$

$$\tag2
\frac{\log{x}}{\log{2}}+\frac{\log{x}}{\log{3}}+\frac{\log{x}}{\log{4}} = 1$$

$$\tag3
\left(\frac{1}{\log{2}}+\frac{1}{\log{3}}+\frac{1}{\log{4}}\right)\log{x} = 1$$

$$\tag4
\left(\frac{1}{\log{2}}+\frac{1}{\log{3}}+\frac{1}{\log{4}}\right) = \frac{1}{\log{x}}$$

$$\tag5
\left(\frac{1}{\log{3}} + \frac{3}{\log{4}}\right) = (\log{x})^{-1}$$

$$\tag6
\left(\frac{1}{\log{3}} + \frac{3}{\log{4}}\right)^{-1} = \log{x}$$

$$\tag7
10^{\left(\frac{1}{\log{3}} + \frac{3}{\log{4}}\right)^{-1}}= x$$

> $$10^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log{3}} + \frac{3}{\log{4}}}}= x$$

Comment: The step from line 3 to line 4 is interesting. Congrats to the upvoters.

Comment: Lines $1$ and $2$ are fair enough, the remaining needs some revision.

Comment: Your are right. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a slightly different approach, let $x=e^u$.  Then

$$1=\log_2x+\log_3x+\log_4x=u(\log_2e+\log_3e+\log_4e)$$

so

$$x=e^u=e^{1/(\log_2e+\log_3e+\log_4e)}$$

Note: $e$ here can be *any* positive number, not just $2.718281828\ldots$.  For example, we might write

$$x=4^{1/(\log_24+\log_34+\log_44)}=4^{1/(3+\log_34)}$$

Since $3\lt4\lt9$, we have $1\lt\log_34\lt2$, with the value of $\log_34$ closer to $1$ than it is to $2$.  If we use the crude approximation $\log_34\approx1$, we get

$$x\approx4^{1/4}=\sqrt2\approx1.414$$

Since $\log_34$ is actually *bigger* than $1$, the exact value of $x$ is somewhat *less* than $\sqrt2$. Closer calculation gives

$$x\approx4^{1/4.2618595}\approx4^{0.234639}\approx1.384416$$

Answer (score -1):

$$ log_v {u}= \dfrac{log_a u}{log_a v} $$

valid for *any arbitrary base $a$*, need not necessarily be $10$ or $e$.

So

$$\log_a{x}\left(\dfrac{1}{\log_a2}+\dfrac{1}{\log_a3}+\frac{1}{\log_a4}\right)=1$$

or

$$x=a^\left({\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{\log_a2}+\dfrac{1}{\log_a3}+\dfrac{1}{\log_a4}}}\right)=f(a)$$

EDIT1:

apparently but in fact $ \ne any \,f(a)$

Consequently $x$ is indeterminate... as we are free to choose *any base*.

Sorry, since $ a^{log_a u} = \,u $ it has a cancelling effect ... hastily over sighted on pure visual/structural inspection of the above. (  I wished only to say "consequently $x$ is *independent* of base... as we are free to choose *any base* " ) etc. ...because I placed more value on base independence as relevant for this question.

```
g[u_] = Log[u] (1/Log[3] + 1/Log[4] + 1/Log[2]);
ParametricPlot[{a, a^(1/g(a))}, {a, 1, 12}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

that yields a base free  $ x \approx 1.3844.$

Comment: Are you serious ? (By the way, $x=1.3844171570591...$.)

Comment: Edited answer as above.